# Every - mixing singular and plural in one sentence

Tags: singular-vs-plural, qualifiers

I'm confused by the use of plural and singular when **Every** is use. Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. *Every business has* its own unique set of challenges, resulting in a different *approach* even if *they* have the same *goals*.
2. Every businesses have their own unique set of challenges, resulting
   in different approaches even if they have the same goals.

Comment: There is no such thing as *every businesses, so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Every` refers to individual items only, sometimes emphasized by saying, `each and every`. `Every` is not used with plurals or uncountable nouns, such as `water.

The word `all` refers to the totality, as in `all businesses`.

Comment: Thanks. Does the following make better sense? Each and every business has its own unique set of challenges, resulting in a different approach even if they have the same goals.

Comment: Problem: the antecedent of "they", plural, is "business", singular. Actually, it makes sense as written, and a casual speaker might say it that way, but it would be better using "each has the same goal."

Comment: Thank you! That sounds so much better!

Comment: @Jalene I prefer keeping *they have the same goals*. It sounds more natural to me, and I don't find the mixture of the singular first half with the plural second half to be jarring—it's something that's commonly done, so it's idiomatic. (In fact, using *each has the same goal* in the second half sounds awkward and unidiomatic to me—even if its not actually wrong.) If you wish, you could emphasize the plurality (and the localized correctness) in the second have with *they **all** have the same goals*.

Comment: @JasonBassford, agreed, that is how people speak and would be appropriate in dialog, but if this is an *academic* exercise, or for a company publication that might be criticized, formal English is preferable.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you! Adding "all" makes it more impactful!